# Use ObjectDataSource as DataSourceControlID of RadFilter control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a `RadFilter` control in my aspx page and i want to set an `ObjectDataSource` as it's `DataSourceControlID` property.

This is my code :

```
<telerik:RadSkinManager ID="RadSkinManager1" runat="server" />
<telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server" ID="RadAjaxManager1" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
       <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadFilter1">
                  <UpdatedControls>
                       <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadFilter1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                  </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
       <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="objectDataSource1">
               <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="objectDataSource1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
               </UpdatedControls>
       </telerik:AjaxSetting>
   </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"></telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<div class="demo-container">
   <div class="filterDiv">
        <telerik:RadFilter runat="server" ID="RadFilter1" DataSourceControlID="objectDataSource1" ShowApplyButton="false"></telerik:RadFilter>
   </div>
</div>
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="objectDataSource1" SelectMethod="MyMethod" TypeName="MyNameSpace.MyClass" ></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

But i receive the following error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

**Note 1:** The `SelectMethod` of my `ObjectDataSource` returns a `DataTable`.

**Note 2:** I do not want to use `RadGrid` but also i want to create a filter expression by `RadFilter` and then save it in my database.

**Edit :**

```
   [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadFilter.ExtractResultCollection(EventArgs args) +97
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadFilter.OnDataSourceSelectedHandler(Object sender, EventArgs args) +47
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.OnSelected(ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.InvokeMethod(ObjectDataSourceMethod method, Boolean disposeInstance, Object& instance) +648
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1609
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
```

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @SonerGönül, Thanks, but i know what NullReferenceException is however i received error when the datasource of RadFilter is going to set. Please check the Edit part in my question.

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi Can you verify your select method is not returning Null ? Cause i tried in my solution it doesn't cause error...